# MS Edge's component WebView2 crashes C++ application on closing window

Tags: c++, wpf, microsoft-edge, webview2

```
MS Edge runtime: 94.0.992.31

Nuget package : Microsoft.Web.WebView2  1.0.992.28
```

We have two solutions : Managed C++ app and Wpf GUI library. 
In the Managed C++ we consume wpf's views. 
Everything was OK while we were using old System.Windows.Controls.WebBrowser. No crashes. But, well, rendered HTML becomes more complex and harder to be properly rendered in old control. So, after some investigation we decided to use top edge control from Microsoft. Everything was OK while we were testing just WPF GUI project.
 We were so happy and excited how good it is.
 Then when we tried to integrate updated view to C++ app problems arised. If user selects from menu appropriate window with hosted WebView2 control -> it successfully show up all necessary stuff. It's really great how it renders even very complex html/css. 
 But, when user clicks in "cross" button that close the appropriate c++ window (who hosts wpf view with integrated WebView2 component) it freezes immedeately the whole application and after few seconds application is crashed.  The log is empty, it's crashed so fast that application not able to make any record in the log. 
Can you provide some ideas how to find workaround for it, please ...?

Update:
I've subscribed  in C++ application to Application.DispatcherUnhandledException Event from WPF

```
void CMainFrame::OnDispatcherUnhandledException(System::Object^ sender, System::Windows::Threading::DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs^ e)
{
    System::String ^ expMessage =  e->Exception->ToString();
}
```

it provides the following Error Message 
**System.InvalidOperationException: CoreWebView2 members cannot be accessed after the WebView2 control is disposed. System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: The group or resource is not in the correct state to perform the requested operation. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007139F)** 
it looks strange because window is closed and we don't try to open it again. 
here is a callstack:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: CoreWebView2 members cannot be accessed after the WebView2 control is disposed. ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: The group or resource is not in the correct state to perform the requested operation. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007139F) at Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core.Raw.ICoreWebView2Controller.set_IsVisible(Int32 IsVisible) at Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core.CoreWebView2Controller.set_IsVisible(Boolean value) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core.CoreWebView2Controller.set_IsVisible(Boolean value) at Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Wpf.WebView2.UIElement_IsVisibleChanged(Object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) at System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseDependencyPropertyChanged(EventPrivateKey key, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args) at System.Windows.UIElement.OnIsVisibleChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) at System.Windows.DependencyObject.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) at System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args) at System.Windows.UIElement.UpdateIsVisibleCache() at System.Windows.UIElement.InvalidateForceInheritPropertyOnChildren(Visual v, DependencyProperty property) at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.InvalidateForceInheritPropertyOnChildren(DependencyProperty property) at System.Windows.UIElement.OnIsVisibleChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) at System.Windows.DependencyObject.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) at System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args) at System.Windows.UIElement.UpdateIsVisibleCache() at System.Windows.UIElement.InvalidateForceInheritPropertyOnChildren(Visual v, DependencyProperty property) at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.InvalidateForceInheritPropertyOnChildren(DependencyProperty property) at System.Windows.UIElement.OnIsVisibleChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) at System.Windows.DependencyObject.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) at System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args) at System.Windows.UIElement.UpdateIsVisibleCache() at System.Windows.UIElement.InvalidateForceInheritPropertyOnChildren(Visual v, DependencyProperty property) at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.InvalidateForceInheritPropertyOnChildren(DependencyProperty property) at System.Windows.UIElement.OnIsVisibleChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) at System.Windows.DependencyObject.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) at System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args) at System.Windows.UIElement.UpdateIsVisibleCache() at System.Windows.UIElement.InvalidateForceInheritPropertyOnChildren(Visual v, DependencyProperty property) at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.InvalidateForceInheritPropertyOnChildren(DependencyProperty property) at System.Windows.UIElement.OnIsVisibleChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) at System.Windows.DependencyObject.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) at System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args) at System.Windows.UIElement.UpdateIsVisibleCache() at System.Windows.UIElement.InvalidateForceInheritPropertyOnChildren(Visual v, DependencyProperty property) at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.InvalidateForceInheritPropertyOnChildren(DependencyProperty property) at System.Windows.UIElement.OnIsVisibleChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) at System.Windows.DependencyObject.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) at System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args) at System.Windows.UIElement.UpdateIsVisibleCache() at System.Windows.UIElement.InvalidateForceInheritPropertyOnChildren(Visual v, DependencyProperty property) at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.InvalidateForceInheritPropertyOnChildren(DependencyProperty property) at System.Windows.UIElement.OnIsVisibleChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) at System.Windows.DependencyObject.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) at System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args) at System.Windows.UIElement.UpdateIsVisibleCache() at System.Windows.UIElement.InvalidateForceInheritPropertyOnChildren(Visual v, DependencyProperty property) at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.InvalidateForceInheritPropertyOnChildren(DependencyProperty property) at System.Windows.UIElement.OnIsVisibleChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) at System.Windows.DependencyObject.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) at System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args) at System.Windows.UIElement.UpdateIsVisibleCache() at System.Windows.UIElement.InvalidateForceInheritPropertyOnChildren(Visual v, DependencyProperty property) at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.InvalidateForceInheritPropertyOnChildren(DependencyProperty property) at System.Windows.UIElement.OnIsVisibleChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) at System.Windows.DependencyObject.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) at System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args) at System.Windows.UIElement.UpdateIsVisibleCache() at System.Windows.UIElement.InvalidateForceInheritPropertyOnChildren(Visual v, DependencyProperty property) at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.InvalidateForceInheritPropertyOnChildren(DependencyProperty property) at System.Windows.UIElement.OnIsVisibleChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) at System.Windows.DependencyObject.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) at System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args) at System.Windows.UIElement.UpdateIsVisibleCache() at System.Windows.UIElement.InvalidateForceInheritPropertyOnChildren(Visual v, DependencyProperty property) at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.InvalidateForceInheritPropertyOnChildren(DependencyProperty property) at System.Windows.UIElement.OnIsVisibleChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) at System.Windows.DependencyObject.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) at System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args) at System.Windows.UIElement.UpdateIsVisibleCache() at System.Windows.UIElement.InvalidateForceInheritPropertyOnChildren(Visual v, DependencyProperty property) at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.InvalidateForceInheritPropertyOnChildren(DependencyProperty property) at System.Windows.UIElement.OnIsVisibleChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) at System.Windows.DependencyObject.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) at System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args) at System.Windows.UIElement.UpdateIsVisibleCache() at System.Windows.UIElement.InvalidateForceInheritPropertyOnChildren(Visual v, DependencyProperty property) at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.InvalidateForceInheritPropertyOnChildren(DependencyProperty property) at System.Windows.UIElement.OnIsVisibleChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) at System.Windows.DependencyObject.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) at System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args) at System.Windows.UIElement.UpdateIsVisibleCache() at System.Windows.UIElement.InvalidateForceInheritPropertyOnChildren(Visual v, DependencyProperty property) at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.InvalidateForceInheritPropertyOnChildren(DependencyProperty property) at System.Windows.UIElement.OnIsVisibleChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) at System.Windows.DependencyObject.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) at System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args) at System.Windows.UIElement.UpdateIsVisibleCache() at System.Windows.UIElement.InvalidateForceInheritPropertyOnChildren(Visual v, DependencyProperty property) at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.InvalidateForceInheritPropertyOnChildren(DependencyProperty property) at System.Windows.UIElement.OnIsVisibleChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) at System.Windows.DependencyObject.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) at System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args) at System.Windows.UIElement.UpdateIsVisibleCache() at System.Windows.UIElement.InvalidateForceInheritPropertyOnChildren(Visual v, DependencyProperty property) at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.InvalidateForceInheritPropertyOnChildren(DependencyProperty property) at System.Windows.UIElement.OnIsVisibleChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) at System.Windows.DependencyObject.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) at System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args) at System.Windows.UIElement.UpdateIsVisibleCache() at System.Windows.UIElement.InvalidateForceInheritPropertyOnChildren(Visual v, DependencyProperty property) at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.InvalidateForceInheritPropertyOnChildren(DependencyProperty property) at System.Windows.UIElement.OnIsVisibleChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) at System.Windows.DependencyObject.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) at System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args) at System.Windows.UIElement.UpdateIsVisibleCache() at System.Windows.UIElement.InvalidateForceInheritPropertyOnChildren(Visual v, DependencyProperty property) at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.InvalidateForceInheritPropertyOnChildren(DependencyProperty property) at System.Windows.UIElement.OnIsVisibleChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) at System.Windows.DependencyObject.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) at System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args) at System.Windows.UIElement.UpdateIsVisibleCache() at System.Windows.UIElement.InvalidateForceInheritPropertyOnChildren(Visual v, DependencyProperty property) at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.InvalidateForceInheritPropertyOnChildren(DependencyProperty property) at System.Windows.UIElement.OnIsVisibleChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) at System.Windows.DependencyObject.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) at System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args) at System.Windows.UIElement.UpdateIsVisibleCache() at System.Windows.UIElement.InvalidateForceInheritPropertyOnChildren(Visual v, DependencyProperty property) at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.InvalidateForceInheritPropertyOnChildren(DependencyProperty property) at System.Windows.UIElement.OnIsVisibleChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) at System.Windows.DependencyObject.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) at System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args) at System.Windows.UIElement.UpdateIsVisibleCache() at System.Windows.UIElement.InvalidateForceInheritPropertyOnChildren(Visual v, DependencyProperty property) at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.InvalidateForceInheritPropertyOnChildren(DependencyProperty property) at System.Windows.UIElement.OnIsVisibleChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) at System.Windows.DependencyObject.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) at System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args) at System.Windows.UIElement.UpdateIsVisibleCache() at System.Windows.UIElement.InvalidateForceInheritPropertyOnChildren(Visual v, DependencyProperty property) at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.InvalidateForceInheritPropertyOnChildren(DependencyProperty property) at System.Windows.UIElement.OnIsVisibleChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) at System.Windows.DependencyObject.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) at System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args) at System.Windows.UIElement.UpdateIsVisibleCache() at System.Windows.UIElement.InvalidateForceInheritPropertyOnChildren(Visual v, DependencyProperty property) at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.InvalidateForceInheritPropertyOnChildren(DependencyProperty property) at System.Windows.UIElement.OnIsVisibleChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) at System.Windows.DependencyObject.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) at System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args) at System.Windows.UIElement.UpdateIsVisibleCache() at System.Windows.UIElement.InvalidateForceInheritPropertyOnChildren(Visual v, DependencyProperty property) at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.InvalidateForceInheritPropertyOnChildren(DependencyProperty property) at System.Windows.UIElement.OnIsVisibleChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) at System.Windows.DependencyObject.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) at System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args) at System.Windows.UIElement.UpdateIsVisibleCache() at System.Windows.UIElement.InvalidateForceInheritPropertyOnChildren(Visual v, DependencyProperty property) at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.InvalidateForceInheritPropertyOnChildren(DependencyProperty property) at System.Windows.UIElement.OnIsVisibleChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) at System.Windows.DependencyObject.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) at System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args) at System.Windows.UIElement.UpdateIsVisibleCache() at System.Windows.UIElement.InvalidateForceInheritPropertyOnChildren(Visual v, DependencyProperty property) at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.InvalidateForceInheritPropertyOnChildren(DependencyProperty property) at System.Windows.UIElement.OnIsVisibleChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) at System.Windows.DependencyObject.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) at System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args) at System.Windows.UIElement.UpdateIsVisibleCache() at System.Windows.UIElement.InvalidateForceInheritPropertyOnChildren(Visual v, DependencyProperty property) at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.InvalidateForceInheritPropertyOnChildren(DependencyProperty property) at System.Windows.UIElement.OnIsVisibleChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) at System.Windows.DependencyObject.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) at System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args) at System.Windows.UIElement.UpdateIsVisibleCache() at System.Windows.UIElement.InvalidateForceInheritPropertyOnChildren(Visual v, DependencyProperty property) at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.InvalidateForceInheritPropertyOnChildren(DependencyProperty property) at System.Windows.UIElement.OnIsVisibleChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) at System.Windows.DependencyObject.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) at System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args) at System.Windows.UIElement.UpdateIsVisibleCache() at System.Windows.UIElement.InvalidateForceInheritPropertyOnChildren(Visual v, DependencyProperty property) at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.InvalidateForceInheritPropertyOnChildren(DependencyProperty property) at System.Windows.UIElement.OnIsVisibleChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) at System.Windows.DependencyObject.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) at System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args) at System.Windows.UIElement.UpdateIsVisibleCache() at System.Windows.PresentationSource.RootChanged(Visual oldRoot, Visual newRoot) at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.set_RootVisualInternal(Visual value) at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.Dispose(Boolean disposing) at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.OnHwndDisposed(Object sender, EventArgs args) at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.Dispose(Boolean disposing, Boolean isHwndBeingDestroyed) at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled) at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o) at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs) at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
```

Comment: May I know if you have got any chance to check my answer? I am glad to help if you have any other questions.

Comment: @XudongPeng sorry for my silence. Yes, your answer was useful. We temporaly started to use CefSharp. We are eager to use MS Edge engine for many reasons, but for now seems it's not possible. We experimented to use older version of ms edge engine (like you advised us), we were also trying to use some workarounds from  WebView2Feedback github repository, but  nothing helped us much. We've found CefSharp is more stable (for October 2021). We integrated it without any problem to our app. But, we are waiting for more stable release of MS Edge engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some related searches on this issue and I found that this is a known issue. The runtime `94.0.988.0+` seems to be affected, please refer to this case: [Process crashed after app started](https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Feedback/issues/1678).

So this seems to be unable to solve the problem from the code, so if you need to solve the problem now, you may need to install a previous version of Edge Dev, or wait for Edge to update.

Comment: seems this bug not fixed yet? we just tried to install latest WebView runtime, use latest NuGet packages and it still crashes in C++ app.

Comment: is there any way to download old runtime? for now we could just download latest one but it would be great to download runtime before 94 version (that, seems provides this crash)

Comment: I've found workaround: when C++ closes the from -> handle OnClose event -> call  DisposeCustom() method on WPF view -> it  does soemthing like this:             WebView2MainDocument.Dispose();
WebView2MainDocument.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
then it is OK
but it is required a lot of work for updating all wpf and c++ views. 
I there better solution?